# How is jekyll related to ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

I have a pretty general question regarding Jekyll. When I try to install it on my mac I get an error saying I don't have write permissions to the ruby directory. After looking around online I've found that you can fix this by installing a ruby version manager. My question is why does this work? Is Jekyll essentially an extended version of Ruby? How are they related architecturally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think Jekyll is a Ruby Gem. So that would mean it is written in Ruby, and needs the Ruby interpreter on your system to install/run it.

RVM is just a tool to help you manage your different Ruby versions (because you could potentially install multiple versions at the same time, for different users for example).

Comment: The other reason to install rvm is because it lets you install Ruby and ruby gems without needing root privileges.

Comment: I mean, you don't have to use rvm for that, at least I think. (edit: It only needs root privileges because you probably installed it as root (via sudo apt-get). Nothing prevents you from installing it locally)

Comment: This might depend upon the OS.  On Debian Linux, you can't install Ruby or Ruby gems without root privileges.  After rvm is installed, you can install Ruby and gems to your home directory; no root privileges needed.

Comment: What do you mean "you can't"... First url in google for "Installing ruby without root access" http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-ruby-on-linux-as-a-user-other-than-root/

Comment: Also, rvm can install ruby and ruby gems without root access, that means that any other user can do that too.

Comment: I should have said, "... because it lets you _easily_ install Ruby and ruby gems without needing root privileges."  That blog post shows the painful way to do it.

Comment: Right.. This one looks painful, but all you need is to download the package, unzip it, create some folders and put everything you need on your path.

Answer (score 4):

[Jekyll](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll) is built in Ruby and is available as [rubygem](https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll). That's why it requires Ruby to build. It provides command line interface to carry out [deploy](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/) and [other operations](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/) and provides minimalistic HTTP server.

It is also equipped to convert markdown to HTML using [redcarpet ruby gem](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet).

It's AWESOME.

Comment: If it only requires Ruby to build why does it need write permissions to the Ruby directory?

Comment: @intA: it requires ruby to run. As it is a ruby gem, it wants to be installed in your ruby's gems directory. If you're using system ruby, then gems directory is system directory and as such, is protected from writes. You either need to use `sudo` to escalate your privileges, or install ruby to a non-system path (that's what ruby switchers do)